# How can I get Hello World app work in TideSDK Ubuntu?

Tags: tidesdk

I have installed the TideSDK and downloaded the Hello World example but it doesn't launch.
Here it is what I get in the console:

```
Preparing to package and launch desktop app. One moment...
Staging HelloWorld
-> Copying contents from /home/ann/TideSDK-HelloWorld-master to /home/ann/TideSDK-HelloWorld-master/dist/linux/HelloWorld
-> Copying installer from /home/ann/.tidesdk/sdk/linux/1.3.1-beta/installer to /home/ann/TideSDK-HelloWorld-master/dist/linux/HelloWorld
-> Copying tiboot to /home/ann/TideSDK-HelloWorld-master/dist/linux/HelloWorld
signal caught: 3
Done launching!
```

and that's all. the app isn't lauched. Please help me to fix this problem.
Thanks a lot!